# Raise network issues Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, virtualbox-networking

I'm having issues with my Ubuntu LAMP server.  I've setup static addresses on the /etc/network/interfaces and can't ping my default-gateway or member servers on the network.

Here's the static ip address config and ip address status.  Firewall has been disabled for now.  When I try to restart networking services it fails.  But I can force the interfaces up with IFUP command.  but for some reason I can't ping the gateway of 10.10.0.1
[Ubuntu Addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nduWU.jpg)

[Ubuntu interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ygy6D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove extra complexity in your interfaces file.  Something like this should work.  You don't need to add a `route` when both interfaces use the same gateway.

```
auto ens160 ens192
iface ens160 inet static
    address 10.10.0.130/16
    mtu 1500

iface ens192 inet static
    address 10.10.0.131/16
    gateway 10.10.0.1
    dns-nameservers 10.10.0.5 10.10.0.127
    mtu 1500
```

Comment: Ok..  I can change it this evening and test it.